# LDAP Feeds example not importing new users - Undefined index: count in FeedsLdapEntryParser

Tags: feeds, authentication-authorization

I followed the [LDAP Feeds example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/lightweight-directory-access-protocol-ldap/ldap-feeds-example-usage) from the documentation and the query test returns the user fields just fine, but after launching the cron job manually I get **"There are no new users."** + notice:

> "Notice: **Undefined index: count in** FeedsLdapEntryParser->parse() (line
>   20 of
>   /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/ldap/ldap_feeds/FeedsLdapEntryParser.inc).
>   LDAP Users Imported Successfully."

I triple checked my configurations, as well as the mapping which got **unique targets** for both User name (name) and mail. I also posted in the [drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap/issues/297908) issue as I would think importing users via LDAP is a very much needed function.

Has anybody been successful importing that way or any idea why the count is making issues?

FYI my LDAP Query Results: count=1574. Could it be limited to certain amount of user entries?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly resolved this but basically I **added GUID as a unique field** with a unique number and while manually running the cron job **/admin/config/system/cron** didn't add the users,

after I went to **/import/ldap_data_to_user_data** and scheduled the LDAP query for import it worked.

Now it also syncs after I run them manually. Not sure what i did wrong or was missing, slightly confused but happy :)